# Insert object with add_to_$rel into a many-to-many relationship with DBIx::Class

Tags: perl, dbix-class

### Problem

I'm trying to build a minimal example where I create a many-to-many
relationship in [`DBIx::Class`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass) and insert some rows into the database.

In my database I have two tables **A** and **C** which are linked by the table **AC**.
I try to insert the values using the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use DB::Main;

my $s = DB::Main->connect("dbi:SQLite:example.db");
my $a1 = $s->resultset('A')->create({a_value => 'a1'});
my $a2 = $s->resultset('A')->create({a_value => 'a2'});
my $a3 = $s->resultset('A')->create({a_value => 'a3'});

$s->resultset('C')->create({c_value => 'c1'});
$s->resultset('C')->create({c_value => 'c2'});

my $c1 = $s->resultset('C')->find(1);
$c1->add_to_as($a1);
```

The values a1 to a3 and c1,c2 get created just fine. When I try to
add the relationship between a1 and c1 into the table **AC**. I get the following error message:

```
Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at /Library/Perl/5.12/DBIx/Class/Relationship/ManyToMany.pm line 88.
```

I think I am following the [Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/lib/DBIx/Class/Relationship/Base.pm#add_to_%24rel) of add_to_$rel to the letter. What am I doing wrong here?

### Schema Definition

I'm using the following database schema which I deploy with [`DBIx::Class::DeploymentHandler`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aDeploymentHandler) into an SQLite database.

File `db/Main.pm`

```
package DB::Main;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Schema/;

our $VERSION = 1;
__PACKAGE__->load_namespaces;
1;
```

File `db/Main/Result/A.pm`

```
package DB::Main::Result::A;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;
__PACKAGE__->table('a');
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  a_id => {
    data_type => 'Integer',
    size      => 8
  },
  a_value => {
    data_type => 'Varchar',
    size      => 50
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key('a_id');
__PACKAGE__->has_many('acs' => 'DB::Main::Result::AC', 'f_a_id');
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('cs' => 'DB::Main::Result::C', 'acs');
1;
```

File `db/Main/Result/C.pm`

```
package DB::Main::Result::C;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;
__PACKAGE__->table('c');
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  c_id => {
    data_type => 'Integer',
    size      => 8
  },
  c_value => {
    data_type => 'Varchar',
    size      => 50
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key('c_id');
__PACKAGE__->has_many('acs' => 'DB::Main::Result::AC', 'f_c_id');
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('as' => 'DB::Main::Result::A', 'acs');
1;
```

File `db/Main/Result/AC.pm`

```
package DB::Main::Result::AC;
use base qw/DBIx::Class::Core/;
__PACKAGE__->table('ac');
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
  f_a_id => {
    data_type => 'Integer',
    size      => 8
  },
  f_c_id => {
    data_type => 'Integer',
    size      => 8
  },
);
__PACKAGE__->set_primary_key('f_a_id', 'f_c_id');
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to('a' => 'DB::Main::Result::A', 'f_a_id');
__PACKAGE__->belongs_to('c' => 'DB::Main::Result::C', 'f_c_id');
1;
```

Comment: Note that create returns the inserted row object, so you don't have to do the find call. Furthermore many_to_many is a relationship *helper* so you won't be able to use it in joins and prefetches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments in your calls to many_to_many are wrong. Consult the documentation of many_to_many and try the following:

```
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('cs' => 'acs', 'c');
__PACKAGE__->many_to_many('as' => 'acs', 'a');
```

Comment: You are completely right. I must have missed this for maybe a couple of hours ... Thank you very much.